# Woocommerce flat rate shipping issue

Tags: woocommerce

So I have a ecommerce site setup but having a little problem in implementing the flat rate shipping.

I have 3 classes set for their products, small, medium and larger.Now **small** ship for **$15** and additional are free. **Mediums** are **$40** with additional being **$10** and the **large** is **$59** with additional being $25.
so what i have is:

> 15
>
> 30 + (10 * [qty] )
>
> 34 + ( 25 * [qty] )

Now this works fine until they want to do bundle shipping where they let customers create kits. In that case the small will ship for free in either the medium or large box. If they order a medium with the large then the shipping is only $20 more not $40. The products are already in the shipping classes they should be but I don't see a good way say if a large is in the cart then shipping for medium and small changes to reflect that. I need some logic in it to look at categories in the cart and if it sees the large or medium ignore the initial fee.

Any thoughts on how best to address this. I can get there with a dynamic pricing addon but it doesn't convey well on the cart.

Comment: You should need to code conditionals in a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_package_rates` filter hook. if you make a search using this hook you will find a bunch of examples onStackOverFlow.

Comment: I searched exactly that and only came up with 3 none of which were applicable. Basically I just need this setup to check the cart and to subtract the handling fee from the smaller classes if the larger class is in the cart already. So large class, no handling fee on the medium or small class if added. Medium, no handling fee on the small class

Comment: Not so simple than that, as you should need to handle your settings with code (instead of formulas in the shipping classes)… Or you can do it with woocommerce settings, or you do it programmatically… You need to try on your own. Remember to disable shipping methods caches during that period of tries…

Comment: I can do it through the woocommerce settings? Maybe I'm not doing this the right way I've got it currently as 34 + ( 25 * [qty] ) so the first one to ship is 59 and all additional units in that category are 25. Is there a better way to write that? The handling fee basically is just covering the packaging so it only needs to be applied to the first item in the cart and use the amount for the larger item in the cart.